# In java, how to clear byte[] array inside every method to protect the value from memory dump?

Tags: java, memory-dump

In java,

If I run below code, pwd value exists all over the memory because byte array value is copied to digest method which also copies the value to some other methods.

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest

    byte[] pwd = "some_pwd".getBytes();
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        byte[] hash = md.digest(pwd);
    }
```

Memory dump software shows the password value which my customer does not like.

I checked that byte[] is copied by value from method to method.

Is there anyway to protect the important byte array value ?

Comment: No. Your code has do deal with the password value (even just to hash it) so it has to occur in the programs RAM. Your only option is to make variable holding the password as short living as possible (limit its scope).

Comment: just think about it, even if you could pass the array as reference, if you dump the memory while you are using this array, you will be able to see the value(not as often, but still at least 1 time)

Answer (score 4):

Password text should preferably not be passed as String, but let's assume this is an example:

Then ensure the bytes do not occur in the strings for the test.

```
byte[] pwd = "rnld^ovc".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // "some_pwd"
for (int i = 0; i < pwd.length; ++i) {
    pwd[i]++;
}
```

And then the solution:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //byte[] hash = md.digest(pwd);
    for (byte b : pwd) {
        md.update(b - 1); // Maybe -1 if the string was the real password
    }
    byte[] hash = md.digest();
}
Arrays.fill(pwd, (byte)0);
```

Now the MessageDigest cannot maintain a copy of the array on the call to digest.

If you do not want to even have the pwd array, you would need to just take a char/byte at a time from the password field.

Comment: I think you forgot `b -1`, otherwise you calculate a hash for a different value

Comment: hmmm, I don't know, I'm still not 100% satisfied :) but I think it's the best you can do...

Comment: @JohnnyAW I meant that the string contains a cheap -1 encryption, so a memory dump does not show it, and pwd contains the real password; but otherwise - 1 is indeed needed.

Comment: The irony is, that probably at the end the actual passwords are "secret" or "12345678".

Comment: good one, so much afford to keep 123456 as safe as possible :)

Comment: btw. I think you want to put `byte[] hash = md.digest();` out from the outer for-loop, just before `Arrays.fill(pwd, (byte)0);`

Comment: @JohnnyAW as both original and this code is for testing only, for a memory dump, I kept to the old functionality. But yes, many updates and one hash at the end.